# Working with two editor paradigms

Tags: visual-studio, vim, ide, editor

I currently work with both Visual Studio, Eclipse/Rad, and Vim heavily.  Visual Studio and Eclipse don't present any problems because they're the same paradigm.  However vim (which I use for my *nix work) muddles the issue because it's modal.  I actually like the modal nature of vim and find myself trying to type `esc` `k` `k` in Visual Studio.  Does anyone have a suggestion about how to make working in the different environments easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always get [ViEmu](http://www.viemu.com/) for Visual Studio and [viPlugin](http://www.viplugin.com/viplugin/) for Eclipse / RAD...

Comment: ViEmu looks good, but man, it's not cheap...

Answer (score 1):

Try use this script:
www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=864

The visual studio script in vim allow you use external command line to work with visual studio. 
The plugin is write in vim-script and python, which means you need to install python so that you can run the script.

The script doesn't need you to have a python-embed version of vim (it can auto detect that), but it is highly recommend you to use a python-embed version for performance.

Before I using this plugin I have same problem with you, at that time I use external tool in Visual Studio which you can find here:
vim.wikia.com/wiki/Calling_gvim_from_MS_Visual_Studio

Also I recommend you to check [exVim](http://code.google.com/p/exvim/) project, which already integrate the Visual Studio plugin in it, and provide an python-embed version